# AWS Facial Rekognition trying to describecollection with BasicAWSCredentials within Android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-iam, amazon-rekognition

I'am trying to make an Android application that can connect with AWS Facial Rekognition without the use of S3, Cognito or the Amplify framework. I want to hard code my accessKey and secretKey in the application. Now I made a really simple example application, so I can test the functions of Rekognition within Android Studio (that's the main purpose).

I'm calling an object of the class "DoIets" when I'am pressing the button. But I'm getting an error, and I don't see anything wrong. I allow internet connections in the AndroidManifest.xml, and the user with the accesKey en secretKey has the AmazonRekognitionFullAccess policy. In the gradle file, I have imported the 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.10.+' and also the 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-rekognition:2.10.0'.

This is the class "DoeIets.java"

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognition;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.DescribeCollectionRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.DescribeCollectionResult;

public class DoIets {

public void main() {
    Log.w("Test", "In DoIets Class");

    String collectionId = "MyCollectionName";
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("MYACCESKEY", "MYSECRETKEY");
    AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentials);
    rekognitionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

    DescribeCollectionRequest request = new DescribeCollectionRequest().withCollectionId(collectionId);
    DescribeCollectionResult describeCollectionResult = rekognitionClient.describeCollection(request);

    Log.w("Test", "Face count" + describeCollectionResult.getFaceCount());
}
}
```

The errors that I get are the following.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: be.example.testing, PID: 10174
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:162)
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:371)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.invoke(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:3006)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.describeCollection(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:762)
    at be.example.testing.DoIets.main(DoIets.java:25)
    at be.example.testing.MainActivity.doIets(MainActivity.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10174 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Android is not happy with you performing a networking request (blocking call) on the main thread. Making the method asynchronous will fix the problem.

See this related question:

[How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/695787)